# Estimating limit cycle of ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at a system of ODEs:

$$\dot{x} = -y - \epsilon^2 x + xy^2$$
$$\dot{y} = x  -\epsilon^2 y - x^2$$

After plotting these in Matlab I can see there is a limit cycle very close to the origin and now I'm trying to use perturbation theory to find an estimate of the limit cycle.

I'd like to first find a first order approximation by setting $\epsilon = 0$ but I'm struggling to the solve even the resulting first order equation? Is it possible to discard the terms $xy^2$ and $x^2$ because I know that the limit cycle is very close to the origin? I've also tried to use polar coordinates to find a first order approximation but I haven't had much luck there either.

Thanks for any help